# injecting HTML lines using knitr markdown

Tags: r, knitr

Is there a way to inject R code output into the generated document without the sourounding format tags `<pre><code class="r">` or `<pre><code>`? I ask this because I want to use .Rmd not .Rhmtl but at the same time inject some extra HTML lines. Doing so using e.g. `cat("HTML code")` will fail as the output is sourrounded by `<pre><code>`.

The example I try to run the follwing .Rmd file (with additional HTML lines) which file not work out right:

````
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.display == 'none')
    e.style.display = 'block';
  else
    e.style.display = 'none';
}
//-->
</script>  

```{r}
1:10
```

<a onclick="toggle_visibility('answer_1');"><b><u>Antwort anzeigen</b></u></a>
<div id="answer_1" style=display:none>
```{r}
1:10
```
</div>
````

Comment: Could you show what you want finally?

Comment: You JS script might do that too for you.

Comment: @kohske What I want is the same format as the usual R output in the 2nd part. I want to be able to show and hide the 2nd part of the output. Currently the of the second part of the output gets destroyed.

Comment: @daroczig: I am new to JavaScript so any ideas are very welcome :)

Comment: What I want is [something like this](http://www.gridhub.uni-bremen.de/public/test.html) but using markdown Rmd.:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did now was following darozcig's advice and I used JS. This solution seems tedious though. Something easier neatly fitting knitr would be nicer! Below my complete .Rmd script.

````
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id); 
  if(e.style.display == 'none')
    e.style.display = 'block';
  else
    e.style.display = 'none';
}

function answer_top(name){
  var injection1 = '<a onclick=toggle_visibility("' + name + '")><b><u>Show answer</b></u></a>\n'
  document.write(injection1 + "\n")
  var injection2 = '<div id="' + name + '"style=display:none>'
  document.write(injection2 + "\n")
}

function answer_bottom() {
  document.write("</div>" + "\n")
}
//-->
</script>  

```{r}
1:10
```

<script type="text/javascript">answer_top("answer1")</script>
```{r}
1:10
```
<script type="text/javascript">answer_bottom()</script>
````

Comment: probably you can ask this guy: http://carlboettiger.info/2012/06/13/Sethi-policy-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with [knitr's hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks#output_hooks).  You'll probably want to check out the source code to see what the default hooks are for render_markdown():

````
> library(knitr)
> render_markdown()
> knit_hooks$get('echo')
NULL
> knit_hooks$get('message')
function (x, options) 
{
    if (strict) {
        str_c("\n\n", indent_block(x), "\n")
    }
    else str_c("\n\n```\n", x, "```\n\n")
}
<environment: 0x2a3f590>
> knit_hooks$get('output')
function (x, options) 
if (output_asis(x, options)) x else hook.t(x, options)
<environment: 0x2a3f590>
> knitr:::output_asis
function (x, options) 
{
    is_blank(x) || options$results == "asis"
}
<environment: namespace:knitr>
````

I'm not sure what exactly hook.t does, but check it out.

Also, have you tried the asis option?  I'm not totally clear on how you want things formatted, but you might be able to get it working with asis.

You can do lots of cool stuff with hooks.

Comment: see https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/hooks-md.R if you are interested in the default output hooks in `knitr`; I agree with you that this question can be better answered by hooks but `chunk hooks` may be even better

Comment: Agreed.  Especially if he doesn't mind changing the Rmd to add options.  I've found it handy to just augment the knitr hooks at knit-time without making changes to the source document.  However, what I was doing was not specific to one or even a few documents, so I didn't want to deal with adding chunk options.  If he just wants to do this for one or two documents, chunk hooks might be better.